# How to write a pcap file with input data given

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, pcap

I'm looking for a way to create a pcap file using python code.

I want to insert source MAC + source IP + dest. IP + a payload file and write it to a pcap file.

Can I do it with Scapy or any other module?